# Material UI remove the yellow background on TextField autofill

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm having a really hard time to remove the yellow background on autofill from the Material UI TextField component.

In older versions I did it this way:

```
const inputStyle = { WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 0 1000px white inset' };
<TextField
    ...
    inputStyle={inputStyle}
/>
```

But in the recent version the `inputStyle` prop was removed and added `InputProps` instead.

I've tried to remove it this way, but the yellow background color still appears:
[image]

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const styles = {
  root: {
    ':-webkit-autofill': {
        WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 0 1000px white inset',
        backgroundColor: 'red !important'
    }
  },
  input: {
    ':-webkit-autofill': {
        WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 0 1000px white inset',
        backgroundColor: 'red !important'
    }
  }
};

const renderTextField = (props) => {
    const {
        classes,
        label,
        input,
        meta: { touched, error },
        ...custom
    } = props;

  return (
    <TextField
        label={label}
        placeholder={label}
        error={touched && error}
        helperText={touched && error}
        className={classes.root}
        InputProps={{
            className: classes.input
        }}
        {...input}
        {...custom}
    />
  );
}

renderTextField.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(renderTextField);
```

Comment: can you please share a link to code sandbox ??or mention how to replicate it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The replacement for `inputStyle` would be `inputProps`:

```
const inputStyle = { WebkitBoxShadow: "0 0 0 1000px white inset" };
<TextField name="last_name" inputProps={{ style: inputStyle }} />
```

`InputProps` vs. `inputProps` is a common point of confusion. Uppercase "I" `InputProps` provides props for the [Input](https://material-ui.com/api/input/) element within `TextField` (`Input` wraps the native `input` in a `div`). Lowercase "i" `inputProps` provides props for the native `input` element rendered within the `Input` component. If you want to provide inline styles to the native `input` element, the code example above will do the trick.

There are also several other ways to do this using classes via `withStyles`.

If you want to use the `className` property, again this needs to be on the `input` (rather than the div wrapping it) in order to have the desired effect. So the following will also work:

```
const styles = {
  input: {
    WebkitBoxShadow: "0 0 0 1000px white inset"
  }
};
const MyTextField = ({classes}) => {
   return <TextField name="email" inputProps={{ className: classes.input }} />;
}
export default withStyles(styles)(MyTextField);
```

If you want to leverage the ":-webkit-autofill" pseudo-class, you just need to adjust your JSS syntax and add the ["&" to reference the selector of the parent rule](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0-alpha.10#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule):

```
const styles = {
  input: {
    "&:-webkit-autofill": {
      WebkitBoxShadow: "0 0 0 1000px white inset"
    }
  }
};
const MyTextField = ({classes}) => {
   return <TextField name="email" inputProps={{ className: classes.input }} />;
}
export default withStyles(styles)(MyTextField);
```

You can also leverage either of these class approaches, but using uppercase "I" `InputProps` via the [`classes`](https://material-ui.com/api/input/#css) property:

```
const styles = {
  input: {
    WebkitBoxShadow: "0 0 0 1000px white inset"
  }
};
const MyTextField = ({classes}) => {
   return <TextField name="email" InputProps={{ classes: { input: classes.input } }} />;
}
export default withStyles(styles)(MyTextField);
```

Here is a working example with all of these approaches:

[image: Edit rr9omj7q0p]

Answer (score 13):

You can add it to a theme on the overrides.

```
overrides: {
  MuiOutlinedInput: {
    input: {
      '&:-webkit-autofill': {
        '-webkit-box-shadow': '0 0 0 100px #000 inset',
        '-webkit-text-fill-color': '#fff'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly looking for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

While above answers worked for solid colors, I needed transparent one, which was being overriden by something so I found other answer on stackoverflow which worked:

```
  // Workaround to remove autofill color from inputs
  input, select {
    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
    background-clip:  text !important;
  }
```