# MaterialUI: How to override the webkit-autofill styles in InputBase component?

Tags: css, reactjs, webkit, material-ui

I have a MaterialUI InputBase element in my React app.
If i turn the autoComplete property on, the styles of the input get "messed up", once they are filled. I also tried the Input component, with the same problem.

I've tried overriding these pseudo elements, in my global CSS file:

```
input:-internal-autofill-previewed,
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
    color:white !important;
}
```

This has no effect, probably because the original code uses the !important keyword too, giving it a priority over mine. I cannot create an ID, which would have higher priority, because MaterialUI doesn't provide this option.

I do not have anythign special in my setup. These are the styles that are injected using WithStyles, and i doubt they have anything to do with it:

```
inputRoot: {
            color: 'inherit',
            width: '100%',
        },
        inputInput: {

            paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit,
            paddingRight: theme.spacing.unit,
            paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit,
            paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 10,
            transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
            width: '100%',           
            [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
                width: 200,
            },
        },
        inputInputQuery: {


            paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit,
            paddingRight: theme.spacing.unit,
            paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit,
            paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
            transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
            width: '100%',
            [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
                width: 200,
            },
        },
```

Is there any way to get this done,without resorting to JS hacks?

Comment: When you say the styles get "messed up", do you mean in ways beyond just the typical yellow background? If you are just trying to eliminate the yellow background, see this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706919/material-ui-remove-the-yellow-background-on-textfield-autofill/54714640#54714640

Comment: I'm having the same issue with an input component and trying to override the default browser `&:-internal-autofill-selected`.